# How to change database Boolean using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, checkbox

Basically I want to send the same message to several recipients and I want it to register with a checkbox if the email was sent to that user or unchecked if it wasn't(The user has to check the checkbox so it registers) and I can't find a way so when a user checks a checkbox it gets updated in the database. I've tried with Ajax but I've no idea how to properly use it. I need some serious help.
My index.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';  
    include_once 'contact.php'; 
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <br>
    <div class="tabela">
    <table class="scroll">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Nome da Escola &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th>
           <th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEmail Geral da Escola&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th>
           <th>&nbsp&nbsp Enviado</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php

            $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Nome,EmailGeral,Enviado FROM escolas");

            while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array()){
                echo    "
                        <tr>
                            <td>".$infoItems['Nome']."</td>
                            <td>".$infoItems['EmailGeral']."</td>
                            <td><input type=\"checkbox\"".($infoItems['Enviado']?' checked':'checked')."\" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    ";

            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="mail">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <button class="butao" type="button" onclick="emailNext();">Adicionar Email</button>
    <div id="addEmail"></div>

    <script>

    function emailNext() {
    var nextEmail, inside_where;
    nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
    nextEmail.type = 'text';
    nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
    nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
    nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';
    nextEmail.placeholder = 'Insira o Email';
    inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
    inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
    return false;
    }

    </script>

    Assunto:<br><textarea rows="1" name="subject" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    Mensagem:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input class="butao" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the connection to the database that I've created:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "escoladb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "can't connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

And finally the contact so I can send emails to the schools that I want:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = implode(',', $_POST['email']);;
    $from = "g.afonso.escola@gmail.com";
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo "<div style=\"font-size:25px;background-color:white;text-align:center;\"> Email Enviado </div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any ajax here. I also don't see how you would get the checkbox state, since it's _before_ the form and not in it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah I've tried using ajax but It only gives me error or it doesn't work. That's why I've deleted it.

Comment: You should show us the code you've tried. We're to help with that. However, you're just outputting a nameless checkbox outside any form and doesn't have any way to check if it's checked or not. You should get your HTML in order.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson First of all, thanks for your input. I know that what I'm trying to do is simple but I just don't have the knowledge and experience to do it, sorry if I'm being intrusive but is there a way for you to see my code with screen sharing software and help me like with skype or discord. I really need to finish this project.

Comment: Don't worry. You're not being intrusive, but SO doesn't work like that. It's a FAQ (so future visitors can benefit from previous questions/answers) where you post the code you've tried, describe the issue you're having and the expected results. It's not the correct place for asking for private help like that. It's also expected that you do a lot of research and attempts to try and solve your issue yourself before posting.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've been doing research non stop since 9am, because of internship. I just can't make it so when a user clicks on a checkbox it updates the database and the checkbox itself.

Comment: I think you are really confused about how the tech stack you are using works. You can't just "click a checkbox" and "update a db", without some communication between the browser and the server.